# Сделать первый столбец QTableWidget постоянно видимым (закрепленным про прокрутке)

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtableview

Есть таблица широкая. Как сделать первый столбец при прокрутке постоянно видимым?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(1, 20, self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_data)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: Визуализация вопроса]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class FreezeTableWidget(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(FreezeTableWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setModel(model)
        self.frozenTableView = QTableView(self)
        self.init()
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.updateSectionWidth)
        self.verticalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.updateSectionHeight)
        self.frozenTableView.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue)
        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(
            self.frozenTableView.verticalScrollBar().setValue)

    def init(self):
        self.frozenTableView.setModel(self.model())
        self.frozenTableView.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.frozenTableView.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.frozenTableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
                QHeaderView.Fixed)
        self.viewport().stackUnder(self.frozenTableView)

        self.frozenTableView.setStyleSheet('''
            QTableView { border: none;
                         background-color: #8EDE21;
                         selection-background-color: #999;
            }''') # for demo purposes

        self.frozenTableView.setSelectionModel(self.selectionModel())
        for col in range(1, self.model().columnCount()):
            self.frozenTableView.setColumnHidden(col, True)
        self.frozenTableView.setColumnWidth(0, self.columnWidth(0))
        self.frozenTableView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.frozenTableView.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.frozenTableView.show()
        self.updateFrozenTableGeometry()
        self.setHorizontalScrollMode(self.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.setVerticalScrollMode(self.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.frozenTableView.setVerticalScrollMode(self.ScrollPerPixel)

    def updateSectionWidth(self, logicalIndex, oldSize, newSize):
        if self.logicalIndex == 0:
            self.frozenTableView.setColumnWidth(0, newSize)
            self.updateFrozenTableGeometry()

    def updateSectionHeight(self, logicalIndex, oldSize, newSize):
        self.frozenTableView.setRowHeight(logicalIndex, newSize)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(FreezeTableWidget, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateFrozenTableGeometry()

    def moveCursor(self, cursorAction, modifiers):
        current = super(FreezeTableWidget, self).moveCursor(cursorAction, modifiers)
        if (cursorAction == self.MoveLeft and
                self.current.column() > 0 and
                self.visualRect(current).topLeft().x() <
                    self.frozenTableView.columnWidth(0)):
            newValue = (self.horizontalScrollBar().value() +
                        self.visualRect(current).topLeft().x() -
                        self.frozenTableView.columnWidth(0))
            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(newValue)
        return current

    def scrollTo(self, index, hint):
        if index.column() > 0:
            super(FreezeTableWidget, self).scrollTo(index, hint)

    def updateFrozenTableGeometry(self):
        self.frozenTableView.setGeometry(
                self.verticalHeader().width() + self.frameWidth(),
                self.frameWidth(), self.columnWidth(0),
                self.viewport().height() + self.horizontalHeader().height())


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(20, 7)
        header = ['Столбец 1', 'Столбец 2', 'Столбец 3', 'Столбец 4', 'Столбец 5', 'Столбец 6', 'Столбец 7',]
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header)
        
        self.tableView = FreezeTableWidget(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableView)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Пример замороженного столбца")
    window.resize(343, 310)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S. Nick, спасибо! =) Мне очень нравятся Ваши примеры, емко и точно.

Comment: @Konstantin пожалуйста.